# Node.js perform a query using the results of another one

Tags: sql-server, node.js

All right, im an all time user of this website, usually just finding things, not asking them.

But this is about to make me go crazy, Im a first timer using Node.js, and i'm actually using it just because I really need it.

The issue is the following:

I have a sql server database, relational and all. I need to retrieve information about restaurants.

The way I divided the information is by handling a restaurant name and on a separate table, restaurant franchises.

I'm getting all the restaurant franchises for each restaurant just fine, but when I want to pair them with the restaurant name (of course, theres more than just a name) it keep taking the last one on the list, I know this happen because the queries are executed in an asynchronous way.

I've been trying for about a week and half to solve this issue, but my expertise in node.js is close to 0 and I'm having trouble understanding how it magically works...

I'll paste the working code below, anybody have ideas? I tried using promises and lately `asyn.EachSeries` but I don't know how to use it correctly.

```
sql.connect(config, function(err){

    if(err) console.log(err);

    var request = new sql.Request();

    request.execute('sp_GetRestaurants')
    .then( rows => {

        rows.recordset.forEach( function(restaurant) {

            Restaurant = {}
            var restaurantInfo = new Array();

            Restaurant.iRestaurantCode = restaurant.id_restaurant;
            Restaurant.sRestaurantName = restaurant.restaurant_name;
            Restaurant.sRestaurantWebsite = restaurant.restaurant_website;
            Restaurant.bEnabled = restaurant.enabled;
            Restaurant.sRestaurantLogo = restaurant.logo;
            Restaurant.sCountry = restaurant.country_name;
            Restaurant.flRestaurantAvg = restaurant.restaurant_avg;

            var infoRequest = new sql.Request();
            infoRequest.input('restaurant_id', restaurant.id_restaurant);
            console.log("por aca")
            infoRequest.execute('sp_GetRestaurantInfo')
            .then( ri => {

                    ri.recordset.forEach( function(info) {
                    Franchise = {};

                    Franchise.iFranchiseID = info.id_address;
                    Franchise.sFranchiseLocation = info.location_desc;
                    Franchise.sFranchiseAddress = info.address_desc;
                    Franchise.sFranchiseNumber = info.phone_number;
                    Franchise.bFranchiseDelivery = info.yn_delivery;
                    Franchise.nLongitude = info.longitude;
                    Franchise.nLatitude = info.latitude;

                    restaurantInfo.push(Franchise);
                  //console.log(restaurantInfo)  

                });

            })
            .then(() => {
                Restaurant.alFrRestaurant = restaurantInfo;
                console.log(Restaurant);
                //db.collection('Restaurant').doc().set(Restaurant)
            })
        })
        return rows;
    })
    .then( () => {
        console.log("Finished");
    })
});
```

Comment: Sorry my first attempt at an answer was a bit incorrect, it should work better now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution literally, 2 hours after I published the question.

It would work like this

```
getRestaurants(function (err, rest){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    //console.log(rest);
    sql.close();
    getRestaurantInfo(rest, function(err, resto) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        //console.log(resto);
        sql.close();
    })
})

function getRestaurants(getRestaurantCB){

    sql.connect(config, function(err) {

        if(err) {
            console.log("Connection error ", err);
            getRestaurantCB(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log("Connected to database");

        var request = new sql.Request();

        request.execute('sp_GetRestaurants')
        .then( rows => {
            console.log("getRestaurant done");
            getRestaurantCB(null, rows);
        })
    })    
}

function getRestaurantInfo(restaurants, getRestaurantInfoCB) {

    sql.connect(config, function(err) {

        if(err) {
            console.log("Connection error ", err);
            getRestaurantInfoCB(err);
            return;
        }

        var restaurantInfo = new Array();
        async.eachSeries(restaurants.recordset, function (id, cb) {
            setTimeout(function() {

                Restaurant = {}
                var restaurantInfo = new Array();

                Restaurant.iRestaurantCode = id.id_restaurant;
                Restaurant.sRestaurantName = id.restaurant_name;
                Restaurant.sRestaurantWebsite = id.restaurant_website;
                Restaurant.bEnabled = id.enabled;
                Restaurant.sRestaurantLogo = id.logo;
                Restaurant.sCountry = id.country_name;
                Restaurant.flRestaurantAvg = id.restaurant_avg;

                var infoRequest = new sql.Request();
                infoRequest.input('restaurant_id', id.id_restaurant);
                infoRequest.execute('sp_GetRestaurantInfo')
                .then( ri => {
                        ri.recordset.forEach( function(info) {
                        Franchise = {};

                        Franchise.iFranchiseID = info.id_address;
                        Franchise.sFranchiseLocation = info.location_desc;
                        Franchise.sFranchiseAddress = info.address_desc;
                        Franchise.sFranchiseNumber = info.phone_number;
                        Franchise.bFranchiseDelivery = info.yn_delivery;
                        Franchise.sLongitude = info.longitude;
                        Franchise.sLatitude = info.latitude;

                        restaurantInfo.push(Franchise);                        
                    });

                })
                .then(() => {
                    Restaurant.alFrRestaurant = restaurantInfo;
                    console.log(Restaurant);
                    db.collection('Restaurant').doc().set(Restaurant)
                    return cb();
                })
            }), 5000;
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Final call");
            getRestaurantInfoCB(null, Restaurant);  
        });
    })
}
```

it runs perfectly. It's a combination of callback functions with async.EachSeries, I'm sure this is basic knowledge to most of you, but I was new to this haha. Plus there wasn't a concrete answer for this, hope this helps other people.

Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `npm install bluebird`, then in your code (*EDIT*: I added explanations at the end):

```
// Add this at the top of your file
var Promise = require('bluebird')

// ... more code ...

sql.connect(config, function(err){

    if(err) console.log(err);

    var request = new sql.Request();

    request.execute('sp_GetRestaurants')
    .then( rows => Promise.map(rows.recordset, function(restaurant) {

        var Restaurant = {}

        Restaurant.iRestaurantCode = restaurant.id_restaurant;
        Restaurant.sRestaurantName = restaurant.restaurant_name;
        Restaurant.sRestaurantWebsite = restaurant.restaurant_website;
        Restaurant.bEnabled = restaurant.enabled;
        Restaurant.sRestaurantLogo = restaurant.logo;
        Restaurant.sCountry = restaurant.country_name;
        Restaurant.flRestaurantAvg = restaurant.restaurant_avg;

        var infoRequest = new sql.Request();
        infoRequest.input('restaurant_id', restaurant.id_restaurant);
        console.log("por aca")
        return infoRequest.execute('sp_GetRestaurantInfo')
        .then( ri => ri.recordset.map( function(info) {
            Franchise = {};

            Franchise.iFranchiseID = info.id_address;
            Franchise.sFranchiseLocation = info.location_desc;
            Franchise.sFranchiseAddress = info.address_desc;
            Franchise.sFranchiseNumber = info.phone_number;
            Franchise.bFranchiseDelivery = info.yn_delivery;
            Franchise.nLongitude = info.longitude;
            Franchise.nLatitude = info.latitude;

            return Franchise;

        }))
        .then(restaurantInfo => {
            Restaurant.alFrRestaurant = restaurantInfo;
            console.log(Restaurant);
            return Restaurant;
        })
    }))
    .then( restaurants => {
        console.log("Finished");
        console.log(restaurants);
    })
});
```

In your original code, you tried to get multiple queries results by doing a `forEach` on your restaurants result set. It cannot work because the subsequent query (inside the forEach) is also asynchronous code.

What I suggest in the above code is using `Promise.map` on your 1st result set, which returns one promise per restaurant: the one returned by `infoRequest.execute('sp_GetRestaurantInfo')`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to query the Franchise's after you have queried the Restaurant.

To do this I myself would use an npm package called [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). The package adds useful functionality to the javascript native Promise. For this example, I would use [Promise.all()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) function offered by bluebird. This function allows you to return an array of promises. When using the Promise.all function the ".then" function will only be called when all promises in the promise array given to the Promise.all() function have resolved (or been rejected if there is an error).

I have adjusted your code to use bluebird and hopefully solve your problem. I use the Promise.all() twice.

The first time is simply so that I can give the created "Restaurant" object to the promise resolve handler of "infoRequest.execute('sp_GetRestautantInfo')". This use of Promise.all also uses the ".spread". This has the same functionality as ".then" but it just expands the array of promises instead of having to access them through the index of an array. That is why the ".spread" has two parameters.

The second time I use the Promise.all() is to return an array of promises which will each resolve to a Restaurant object. The ".then" will be given the array of Restaurants.

Hopefully this helps solve your problem.

```js
var Promise = require("bluebird");

sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    var request = new sql.Request();

    request.execute('sp_GetRestaurants')
        .then(rows => {

            var promises = new Array();
            rows.recordset.forEach((restaurant) => {

                Restaurant = {};

                Restaurant.iRestaurantCode = restaurant.id_restaurant;
                Restaurant.sRestaurantName = restaurant.restaurant_name;
                Restaurant.sRestaurantWebsite = restaurant.restaurant_website;
                Restaurant.bEnabled = restaurant.enabled;
                Restaurant.sRestaurantLogo = restaurant.logo;
                Restaurant.sCountry = restaurant.country_name;
                Restaurant.flRestaurantAvg = restaurant.restaurant_avg;

                var infoRequest = new sql.Request();
                infoRequest.input('restaurant_id', restaurant.id_restaurant);
                console.log("por aca")
                promises.push(Promise.all([Restaurant, infoRequest.execute('sp_GetRestaurantInfo')])
                    .spread((Restaurant, ri) => {
                        var restaurantInfo = new Array();
                        ri.recordset.forEach((info) => {
                            Franchise = {};

                            Franchise.iFranchiseID = info.id_address;
                            Franchise.sFranchiseLocation = info.location_desc;
                            Franchise.sFranchiseAddress = info.address_desc;
                            Franchise.sFranchiseNumber = info.phone_number;
                            Franchise.bFranchiseDelivery = info.yn_delivery;
                            Franchise.nLongitude = info.longitude;
                            Franchise.nLatitude = info.latitude;

                            restaurantInfo.push(Franchise);
                            //console.log(restaurantInfo)  

                        });
                        Restaurant.alFrRestaurant = restaurantInfo;
                        console.log(Restaurant);
                        return Restaurant;
                        //db.collection('Restaurant').doc().set(Restaurant)
                    }));
            })
            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
        .then((restaurants) => {
            // restaurants is an array of all restaurants with their Franchises
            console.log("Finished");
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few tips to get you going.

When making a promise chain, each "link" in the chain that has asynchronous code should `return` a Promise. So when you `infoRequest.execute('sp_GetRestaurantInfo').then()`, since that is new Promise, it must be returned from the existing `.then()` block or nothing will wait for it.

Do not use the standard array `.forEach` in an asynchronous way. If using Promises, either map your array into an array of Promises for `Promise.all()`, use bluebird's `Promise.each` or if using `async/await`, use `for(let item of array){}`

I hope that helps. As I'm sure you saw in your console.log statements, things were not executing in the order you expected. From the example you posted, the biggest culprit is not returning your new promise inside your `.then()`s.